# VSS files to Linux

Tags: networking

I hate Windows, so I will get much love here.  I love Visio however, and most of the stencils I need for network engineering are in .vss format.  Is there a simplistic way of converting a .vss visio stencil into a .svg or something that yed or dia or whatever drawing diagram, can understand?

Answer (score 1):

- LibreOffice Draw supports the Visio file formats for drawings and stencils: https://librearts.org/2012/11/libreoffice-gets-visio-2013-support/
- Other web-based diagramming tools such as Creately supports Visio file formats too: http://creately.com/blog/announcements/introducing-visio-import/

---

Note that there are two file formats: the traditional VSD and the XML-based VSDX (since Visio 2013). Yoy may find information on the formats and some opensource libraries you can use at:

- The MSDN documentation:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj228622.aspx
- and the LOC preservation site: https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000021.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Libvisio2svg convert vss and vssx perfectly, i dont have tested with vsd and vsdx. Scaling not works.

https://github.com/kakwa/libvisio2svg